# Changing footnote label font in KOMA classes

Tags: fonts, footnotes, koma-script

How can I change the font used for the footnote marker in the body of the text, especially in the KOMA classes?

KOMA-Script lets me change the footnote font label in the footnote, e.g.

```
\addtokomafont{footnotelabel}{\sffamily}
```

but I can't see how to change the label in the text.

A reason for my asking is that I have some fonts that don't have the full complement of characters in `\textsuperscript`, so only some footnote labels in the text appear as they should.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the font of the footnote reference in text with the `footnotereference` element.

The element which fonts you can change with `\setkomafont` and `\addkomafont` are described in

- Tabelle 3.2 of the [German KOMA-Script manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/koma-script/scrguide.pdf), pages 57ff., and
- table 3.2 of the [English KOMA-Scrip manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/koma-script/scrguien.pdf), page 51ff.

### Code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\setkomafont{footnotereference}{\ttfamily}
\begin{document}
Hello World!\footnote{Hello World!}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  This example works, and I'm not sure why I didn't see it in the manual.  Unfortunately, I can't get it to work in another, larger document.  Will try and figure out that problem next.

Comment: @Victor Try to construct [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) similar to that I have used in my answer and feel free to ask a [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117).